# Manage apps crashes when numbers are out of max possible in swift language

Tags: swift

please can you help as I am in a corner....
My apps developped on Xcode with swift is calculating figures which can be out of Int max number and the apps crashes! How can I manage so that the apps manage before crashing? Example: I ask for an Int and calculate "factors" : 30! = 30 x 29 x 28x 27 x...1 but it is clearly over intmax
Thanks for you help
Regards 
K

Comment: Why are you using INT when you know it may exceed the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Double` to solve this problem.
For example to calculate this function calculate the factor of any Int (works for 170, then it's considered as Inf)

```
func factor(integer : Int) -> Double{

    var result : Double = 1

    for newFactor in 1...integer{

        result = result * Double(newFactor)
        print("index",newFactor,"value:",result)
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `overflow operator` just like:

```
var overflowNum = UInt8.max;
overflowNum = overflowNum &* 10;
```

this will be overflowed and finally the value is between the `UInt8.min` and the `Uint8.max`

just like the real big number you've got to `mod` with `UInt8.max`.